# Распарсить XML

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

При обращении к серверу (чужому, естесна), приходит ответ в виде XML такого вида:

```
<code> 
<i param=value param2=value2 и т.д.>
</code>
```

Как его можно попроще распарсить до этих самых значений - param, param2 и тд.
Желательно рабочий пример.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php) или [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php) или [другой "читатель" XML файлов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php)

SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
          . "\n"
          . '<code><i param="value" param2="value2" /></code>';
$params = array();
try
{ 
    $sxe = @new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
    if (isset($sxe->i))
    {
        $i = $sxe->i; // тег <i />
        foreach($i->attributes() as $param => $value) // атрибуты тега <i />
        {
           $params[(string)$param]=(string)$value;
        }
    } else
    {
        // структура не соответствует ожидаемой
    }
} catch (Exception $e) { 
  echo "Bad xml: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
}

echo "params = "; var_export($params);
```

Comment: Если я всё правильно усвоил, то, чтобы достать значение элемента param нужно выполнить вот такие манипуляции?

$dom = new DomDocument();

$myxml = wget('$url');
$dom -> loadXML($myxml);
$parsexml = $dom -> getElementByTagName('param');
echo $pasrexml;

Comment: Я добавил пример кода, но на SimpleXML, который тут более уместен.

Comment: Ну эээээээээ

    $sxe = @new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
    $i = json_decode(json_encode((array)$sxe->i->attributes()), true);

все норм, но эта пара строчек...

Comment: @Fike по поводу @ - ниже есть catch() - там и выводится сообщение об ошибке. Иначе очень много текста генерируется.

По поводу json_decode(json_encode()) - это самая самая простая реализация функции xml_to_array. Заменил на итератор.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, в атрибутах нет никакого xml, там каста (array) более чем достаточно. Какая связь между собакой и catch? Какой текст выводится?

Comment: если убрать собаку и подсунуть невалидный XML : http://take.ms/Dlbel

Comment: @Fike, коллекция атрибутов у узла в XML - это объект http://take.ms/GsO8q

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, который принимает необходимый вид сразу после каста (array), без `json_decode/json_encode`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно распарсить только эту строку не стоит перегружать память дополнительными классами, используйте обычный preg_match

```
$string = '<code> <i param=value param2=value2 и т.д.> </code>';
preg_match_all('/param([\d]*)=(.+?) /is', $string, $params);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => param=value 
            [1] => param2=value2 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [1] => value2
        )

)
```

Comment: Это как раз тот случай когда регулярка плохой вариант.

Comment: Я с вами не соглашусь, т.к. задача стоит распарсить только 1 ответ. Зачем съедать лишнюю память используя SimpleXML или DOM ?
Особенно учитывая что и тот и другой достаточно тяжеловесный.

Comment: @Sect0R, а вы в профайлере определили, что для текущей задачи "тяжесть" парсера имеет хоть какое-то значение?

Comment: Я привел пример, в каком виде всё приходит, а парсить придётся несколько ответов.

Comment: Если они все разные, то да, лучше использовать SimpleXML.
Если же они все одинаковые я бы использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: Вот только вчера "срались" по поводу - парсить ли регулярками HTML. В данном случае XML.

За сутки в голову пришла такая мысль: вот когда говорят - "у меня данные есть по колонкам а,b,c. Как мне найти сумму c?" все сразу пишут SELECT SUM(c) ... но никому в голову не приходит спросить, а у тебя база данных или что? Может там CSV? Тогда надо построчно загружать, делить на колонки, суммировать.

Вот так и с XML (HTML): есть определённый стандарт - читать такие тексты именно теми средствами, которые созданы именно для этого (SAX, DOM, SimpleXML и подобные)

Comment: о кстати, ко вчерашнему срачу.... вот есть у меня ответ от некого сервиса, который может выдать 20Mb html(там таблица) чего мне с ним делать, чтобы запихать строчки этой таблицы в базу ? :)

Comment: По моему опыту работы с DOM скажу что его минус в том что он читает и разбирает сразу весь файл. Для HTML не вкурсе, для XML я использовал XMLReader

Comment: @eicto - 20 метров - это повод отказаться от DomDocument. Прежде всего попробовать прочитать с помощью http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php (потоковый XML парсер, SAX Parser). Ещё вариант - предварительно просканировать HTML через XSLT и выдать результат в более простом XML, а уже потом пройтись по этому упрощённому XML с помощью SAX.

Comment: И ещё, не в тему, а попутно, - 20 метровый JSON тоже фигово читается.

Comment: конечно, и его тоже можно прочитать кусочками. просто иногда нет смысла морочиться, если у провайдера этой штуки что нить поменяется, то  и структура DOM тоже изменится скорее всего,но к тому времени они обещали сделать экспорт CSV. (я наврал, там не 20 метров если целиком а много больше)